# toTimestamp function is not working in select statement cassandra

Tags: cassandra, timeuuid, to-timestamp

I have table as

```
cqlsh> DESC relation.students;

CREATE TABLE relation.students (
    student_id uuid,
    created_at timeuuid,
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (student_id, created_at)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX index_students_student_id ON relation.students (student_id);
```

When I check [`timeuuid` functions](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html), it has `toTimestamp` function, when I try to use that, it gives error.

```
cqlsh> select student_id, name, toTimestamp(created_at) from relation.students where student_id=c2e160e6-27bb-4e25-91ca-e33dc7538d25;
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unknown function 'toTimestamp'"
```

I am using version `2.1`

```
cqlsh> select peer, release_version from system.peers;

 peer        | release_version
-------------+-----------------
  127.0.0.1 |     2.1.14.1272
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Cassandra 2.2  introduced `toTimestamp`**
Check the [Cassandra Release News](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/8b3a60b9a7dbefeecc06bace617279612ec7092d/NEWS.txt#L635)

You can also create your own function. [Cheeck UDF](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDF.html). UDF also introduced in Cassandra 2.2

If you use Cassandra lower than 2.2, you can't use this function.

Comment: Thanks Ashraful, I will see if I can update cassandra.